# How to Format exFAT on Mac with custom block size (Read only problem!)

Tags: mac, exfat

I'm trying to format a CF card on Mac Osx 10.14.4 to exFAT with a specific block size of 4MB, with this terminal command:

```
sudo newfs_exfat -b 4194304 -v exFAT /dev/disk3s1
```

It appears to have worked…

```
Volume name      : exFAT
Partition offset : 63 sectors (32256 bytes)
Volume size      : 125059009 sectors (64030212608 bytes)
Bytes per sector : 512
Bytes per cluster: 4194304
FAT offset       : 2048 sectors (1048576 bytes)
# FAT sectors    : 2048
Number of FATs   : 1
Cluster offset   : 4096 sectors (2097152 bytes)
# Clusters       : 15265
Volume Serial #  : 5e319fb9
Bitmap start     : 2
Bitmap file size : 1909
Upcase start     : 3
Upcase file size : 5836
Root start       : 4
```

…but then it refuses to mount the volume afterwards:

```
Volume on disk3s1 failed to mount
If the volume is damaged, try the "readOnly" option
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: This [question and answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213879/reformat-exfat-with-specific-device-block-size-and-cluster-size?rq=1) may be helpful.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why the 4MB block requirement?

Comment: I was experimenting with larger block sizes than default to write HD raw-video data to the CF card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here! 
Use this wonderful app, which mounts the disk perfectly:
[exfat](https://github.com/relan/exfat)